# Sorting an array of Objects - Nodejs

Tags: javascript, sorting

I am trying to sort the following array based on the num in javascript

```
[ { name: 'sample',
    info: '{"num":10,"type":"detox"}',
    hex: 'bdafa7' },
  { name: 'sample',
    info: '{"num":5,"type":"detox"}',
    hex: 'bdafaj' },
  { name: 'sample',
    info: '{"num":0,"type":"detox"}',
    hex: 'bdafah' },
  { name: 'sample',
    info: '{"num":1,"type":"detox"}',
    hex: 'bdafay' }]
```

How can I achieve this

Comment: Hello! What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of Array.sort and JSON.parse:

```
let v = [ { name: 'sample',
    info: '{"num":10,"type":"detox"}',
    hex: 'bdafa7' },
  { name: 'sample',
    info: '{"num":5,"type":"detox"}',
    hex: 'bdafaj' },
  { name: 'sample',
    info: '{"num":0,"type":"detox"}',
    hex: 'bdafah' },
  { name: 'sample',
    info: '{"num":1,"type":"detox"}',
    hex: 'bdafay' }];

v.sort((a, b) => {
  return JSON.parse(a.info).num - JSON.parse(b.info).num
});
```

Returns

```
[
  {name: "sample", info: "{"num":10,"type":"detox"}", hex: "bdafa7"},
  {name: "sample", info: "{"num":5,"type":"detox"}", hex: "bdafaj"},
  {name: "sample", info: "{"num":1,"type":"detox"}", hex: "bdafay"},
  {name: "sample", info: "{"num":0,"type":"detox"}", hex: "bdafah"}
]
```

Comment: The `sort` callback should return a number, not a boolean. `JSON.parse(a.info).num - JSON.parse(b.info).num` (`-` instead of `<`).

Comment: I wonder how many times I've made that mistake... Thanks Felix Kling.

Comment: That is wonderful !! I was not thinking in this direction that i should have used both array.sort and json.parse.